# How to execute a process in background in a custom shell?

Tags: c, shell, process

I have this exercise:

```
/* smallsh.c */

#include "smallsh.h"
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

char *prompt = "Scrivere un comando>";

void procline(void)     /* tratta una riga di input */
{

  char *arg[MAXARG+1];  /* array di puntatori per runcommand */
  int toktype;      /* tipo del simbolo nel comando */
  int narg;     /* numero di argomenti considerati finora */
  int type; /* FOREGROUND o BACKGROUND */
    
  narg=0;

  do {

    /* mette un simbolo in arg[narg] 
       ed esegue un'azione a seconda del tipo di simbolo */
    
    switch (toktype = gettok(&arg[narg])) {
    
      case ARG:   

        /* se argomento: passa al prossimo simbolo */
        
        if (narg < MAXARG) narg++;
    break;
       

      case EOL:
      case SEMICOLON:
      case AMPERSAND:

        if(toktype == AMPERSAND) type = BACKGROUND;
        else type = FOREGROUND;
      
         /* se fine riga o ';' esegue il comando ora contenuto in arg,
     mettendo NULL per indicare la fine degli argomenti: 
         serve a execvp */

        if (narg != 0) {
          arg[narg] = NULL;
          runcommand(arg, type);
        }
      
    /* se non fine riga (descrizione comando finisce con ';')
           bisogna ricominciare a riempire arg dall'indice 0 */

        if (toktype != EOL)  narg = 0; 

        break;
     }
  }

  while (toktype != EOL);  /* fine riga, procline finita */

}

void runcommand(char **cline, int type) /* esegue un comando */
{
  pid_t pid;
  int exitstat,ret;

  pid = fork();
  if (pid == (pid_t) -1) {
     perror("smallsh: fork fallita");
     return;
  }

  if (pid == (pid_t) 0) {   /* processo figlio */

    /* esegue il comando il cui nome e' il primo elemento di cline,
       passando cline come vettore di argomenti */
    //if(type == 1) sleep(2);
    execvp(*cline,cline);
    perror(*cline);
    exit(1);
  }

  /* non serve "else"... ma bisogna aver capito perche' :-)  */
 
  /* qui aspetta sempre e comunque - i comandi in background 
     richiederebbero un trattamento diverso */

  if(type == 1) { //BACKGROUND
   /*DO SOMETHING*/
  }
  else { //FOREGROUND
    //PART OF THE ORIGINAL CODE
    ret = wait(&exitstat);
    if (ret == -1) perror("wait");
  }
}

int main()
{
  while(userin(prompt) != EOF) 
    procline();
  return 0;
}
```

```
/* input.c */

#include "smallsh.h"

/* buffers per la riga di input e la sua segmentazione in "tokens";
puntatori per scorrere i buffers */

static char inpbuf[MAXBUF], tokbuf[2*MAXBUF],
        *ptr, *tok;

/* array di caratteri che hanno una interpretazione "speciale" 
nei comandi */

static char special[]=
    {' ', '\t', ';', '\n', '\0'};

int userin(char *p)     /* stampa il prompt e legge una riga */
{
  int c, count;

  /* inizializzazioni per altre routines */

  ptr = inpbuf;
  tok = tokbuf;

  /* stampa il prompt */

  printf("%s ",p);

  count=0;

  while(1) {

    if ((c = getchar()) == EOF)
      return(EOF);

    /* si copia il carattere letto in inpbuf; ma se si raggiunge 
       e supera MAXBUF, non si scrive piu' in inpbuf, 
       si continua a leggere fino a newline (si veda sotto) */

    if (count < MAXBUF)
      inpbuf[count++] = c;

    /* se si legge il newline, la riga in input e' finita */

    if (c == '\n' && count < MAXBUF) {
      inpbuf[count] = '\0';
      return(count);
    }

    /*  se e' stato superato MAXBUF, quando si arriva al newline
    si avverte che la riga e' troppo lunga e si 
        va a leggere una nuova riga */

    if (c == '\n') {    /* implicito se si arriva qui: count >= MAXBUF */
      printf("riga in input troppo lunga\n");
      count = 0;
      printf("%s ",p);
    }
  }
}

int gettok(char **outptr)   /* legge un simbolo e lo mette in tokbuf */
{
  int type;

  /* si piazza *outptr in modo che punti al primo byte dove si cominicera'
     a scrivere il simbolo letto */  

  *outptr = tok;

  /* salta eventuali spazi */

  while (*ptr == ' ' || *ptr == '\t') ptr++;

  /* copia il primo carattere del simbolo */

  *tok++ = *ptr;

  /* a seconda del carattere decide il tipo di simbolo */
  
  switch(*ptr++){

    case '\n':
      type = EOL; break;
    case ';':
      type = SEMICOLON; break;
    case '&':
      type = AMPERSAND; break;
    default:
      type = ARG;
      /* copia gli altri caratteri del simbolo */
      while(inarg(*ptr))
        *tok++ = *ptr++;
  }

  /* aggiunge \0 al fondo */

  *tok++ = '\0';
  return(type);

}

int inarg(char c)   /* verifica se c non e' un carattere speciale */
{
   char *wrk;

   for (wrk = special; *wrk != '\0'; wrk++)
       if (c == *wrk) return(0);

   return(1);
}
```

```
/* smallsh.h */

#define FOREGROUND 0 
#define BACKGROUND 1 

#define MAXARG 512  /* numero massimo di argomenti */
#define MAXBUF 512  /* lunghezza massima riga di input */


int inarg(char c);      /* verifica se c non e' un carattere speciale */

int userin(char *p);        /* stampa il prompt e legge una riga */ 

int gettok(char **outptr);  /* legge un simbolo */

void procline();            /* tratta una riga di input */

void runcommand(char **cline, int type);    /* esegue un comando */
```

I must implement a background execution (&) but I have no idea how...
I tried by using wait when execute in foreground and without when execute in background but the prompt and the command output were on the same line and the "cursor" was on new line.
It is possible to obtain this result:

 Command> ls &

//output

Command> //cursor here

instead of:

Command> ls &

Command> //output

 //cursor here

?

Comment: The whole point of running a process in the background is that it runs while the shell continues to run more stuff.  So by definition, if the background command produces output, it will be intermixed with the shell's (and other commands) outputs.  This is why background processes generally always have their stdin/stdout/stderr redirected.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to obtain this result

No it's not, unfortunately. Even when you run a program in the foreground, your cursor is at the end of the output in the terminal. The shell makes that full prompt line pop up when the program terminates to let you know that you have control of the shell again. That doesn't happen with background output because you inherently always have control of the shell, so it wouldn't make sense to have the prompt line pop up arbitrarily.

Also, imagine if you're running several background processes: would you want all of them to cause the prompt line to appear while you're typing something?